# SQL query doesn't work when using UNION?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1054

Here is the snapshot of the query that doesn't work since I added the Union.

```
SELECT fin05_usager.idUsager,
       (SELECT sum(nombreReputation) as nombreReputation
          FROM (SELECT SUM(nombreReputationGagner) as nombreReputation
                 FROM fin05_usager_reputation 
                WHERE fin05_usager_reputation.idUsager = fin05_usager.idUsager
             GROUP BY fin05_usager_reputation.idUsager
        UNION
                SELECT SUM(cc_badge.valeurEnReputation) as nombreReputation
                  FROM cc_badge, fin05_usager_badge
                 WHERE fin05_usager_badge.idBadge = cc_badge.idBadge
                   AND fin05_usager_badge.idUsager = fin05_usager.idUsager) as repuUnion    
       ) as repu
 FROM fin05_usager
WHERE fin05_usager.idUsager = 6
```

The error is : #1054 - Unknown column 'fin05_usager.idUsager' in 'where clause'

If I remove the fin05_usager.idUsager and use directly '6' it does work.

If I remove the union and use only one of the 2 select it works (what ever if I take the FROM fin05_usager_reputation  or the other one FROM cc_badge,  fin05_usager_badge.

Why when using the UNION the error about finding the idUsager appear and without the union no error is found?

## Schema simplified:

fin05_usager: idUsager int(8)

fin05_usager_reputation : idUsager int(8), nombreReputationGagner int(4)

cc_badge : idBadge int(4), valeurEnReputation int(4)

fin05_usager_badge : idUsager int(8), idBadge int(4)

## Note:

I cannot do the subquery directly in the query. I have to use it inside a subquery in the select because in real, the query is very big and already contain Group, etc.

Comment: Here the schema simplified. Like the query, it's a simplified version because everything contain a lot of inner/left join.

Comment: An alternative would be to move the subselect query into a view, and join the view into your current query.

Comment: There's not much more we can do for you if you don't provide the entire query (alter as needed), but I highly doubt you can't incorporate my suggestions into your current query.

Comment: I can't because I already have a GROUP BY...

Comment: MySQL has supported views since 5.0.1: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: GROUP BY only makes sure there are distinct values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

The only way I found for the moment without doing a Group By in the main query (since in the real situation I can't because it does contain already a Group By clause) is to do it in 2 and to merge it with the code... not exaclty what I would like but it works at least:

```
    SELECT fin05_usager.idUsager,

                (SELECT sum(nombreReputationGagner) as nombreReputation1
                FROM fin05_usager_reputation 
                WHERE fin05_usager_reputation.idUsager = fin05_usager.idUsager
                group by fin05_usager_reputation.idUsager) as nombreReputation1
            ,
                (SELECT sum(cc_badge.valeurEnReputation) as nombreReputation2
                FROM cc_badge,  fin05_usager_badge
                WHERE fin05_usager_badge.idBadge = cc_badge.idBadge
                AND fin05_usager_badge.idUsager = fin05_usager.idUsager) as nombreReputation2

    FROM 
        fin05_usager
        where fin05_usager.idUsager = 6
```

In the code I sum the nombreReputation1 and nombreReputation2.

Answer (score 2):

When you mention that removing the UNION causes things to work, I'm betting that you're removing this specifically:

```
UNION
SELECT SUM(cc_badge.valeurEnReputation) as nombreReputation
  FROM cc_badge, fin05_usager_badge
 WHERE fin05_usager_badge.idBadge = cc_badge.idBadge
   AND fin05_usager_badge.idUsager = fin05_usager.idUsager
```

This piece contains the refernce to `fin05_usager.idusager` that the mysql error is referring to.  Subquery access is only allowed to one level - both ways.  Nevermind that you really shouldn't be doing a SELECT within the SELECT clause.  Here's how I reinterpret your query:

```
SELECT fu.idUsager,
       a.nombreReputation + b.nombreReputation AS repuunion
  FROM fin05_usager fu
  JOIN (SELECT fur.idusager,
               SUM(fur.nombreReputationGagner) as nombreReputation
          FROM fin05_usager_reputation fur 
         WHERE fur.idUsager = fin05_usager.idUsager
      GROUP BY fur.idUsager) a ON a.idusager = fu.idusager
  JOIN (SELECT fub.idUsager,
               SUM(ccb.valeurEnReputation) as nombreReputation
          FROM cc_badge ccb
          JOIN fin05_usager_badge fub ON fub.idbadge = ccb.idbadge
      GROUP BY fub.idUsager) b ON b.idusager = fu.idusager
 WHERE fu.idUsager = 6
```

Comment: I have to have sub query... the real query has already Group and a lot of left join, etc. I cannot use directly the way you specified but I do understand your point.

For the union, I have tried to remove both side and both work.

Thanks to telling me that it only works on 1 level, didn't know that.